# Write custom python functions for logical/boolean evaluations without ast module?

Tags: python, parsing, boolean, abstract-syntax-tree

I've written a function that shortens this:

```py
if A>int or B>int or C>int or D>int or...:
    # do something
```

to this:

```py
if ne('>',int,A,B,C,D,...):
    # do something
```

using this function:

```py
def ne(o,c,*args):

    '''
    Creates a string for each evaluation with bool() and "parses" 
    it using bool(eval(string)). Then it returns the any() value.
    '''
    o = str(o)
    args = (str(arg) for arg in args)

    return any((bool(eval(''.join([arg,c,o]))) for arg in args))
```

Is this a sensible way to do this, or do I need to learn the `ast` module and learn parsing of strings from the bottom up? I've heard a lot of people have 
reservations about using `eval` in general.

What should I learn if I want to write my own boolean evaluation systems?

Comment: I'd suggest passing an [*operator*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), so it'd be e.g. `ne(operator.gt, int, A, ...)`, then implemented as `return any(o(c, arg) for arg in args)`. This is a simpler implementation that avoids issues with stringifying and `eval` entirely. If you really want to pass `'>'`, that could just look up the function from a dictionary `{'>': operator.gt, ...}`.

Comment: Oh so that's how you access those. Nice. I would've just added an additional ```if operator not in operator_list``` condition to limit the potential effects of eval().

Comment: That would be slightly safer, but still not very performant, and unable to distinguish e.g. `1` from `'1'` (although `repr(arg)` helps there).